# Quadratic equation optimality without differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Show that for a symmetric matrix $A$:

$$\inf_{x \in \mathbb R^n} x^TAx - 2b^Tx$$

has a solution if and only if $A$ is positive semidefinite and $b$ is in the range of $A$.

---

This is straightforward to show by applying first order optimality conditions using the gradient of the objective. Is there some way to show this without differentiating the objective?

I think this should be possible by considering the orthogonal complement of the range of $A$ and decomposing $b$ into two components: $b = y + z$ where $y \in \text{Im}\,A$ and $z$ such that $A^Tz = 0$.

To show necessity, I am trying to argue (by contradiction) that if $z$ is not the zero vector, then the objective can be made arbitrarily negative since we can take the component of $x$ in the null space of $A$ to have a very negative inner product with $z$. This argument is intuitive, but I am having trouble formalizing it without appealing to the typical first order optimality condition.

Comment: If $b$ is in the range of $A$, then there exists $\eta$ such that $A \eta = b$.

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric I can rewrite the objective as: $x^TA(x - 2\eta)$ where I now want to show that if $A$ is not PSD then this can be made arbitrarily negative. Assuming $A$ is not PSD then there is a subspace where $x^TAx$ is negative, but I'm not sure what that tells me about the expression in question. Any more hints?

Comment: Write $(x-\eta)^\top A (x-\eta)$ instead. Discard the $0$-th order term.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question. The act of writing can lead to great clarity.

Answer (score 1):

We'll show necessity by contradiction.

Call the objective $q(x) = x^TAx - 2b^Tx$.

First let's assume that $A \succeq 0$ but that $b$ is not in the image of $A$:

Take $x = \alpha b$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Recall that if $b \not \in \text{Im}\, A$ then $b \in \text{Ker} \, A$ so that $Ab = 0$. Now the objective is:
$$q(\alpha b) = -2\alpha \|b\|^2$$

which goes to $-\infty$ as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ so that $q$ does not have a solution.

Next let's assume that $b \in \text{Im}\, A$ but there exists some $u \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $u^TAu <0$. Since $b \in \text{Im}\, A$, there exists some $\eta \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $b = A\eta$. Rewriting $q$ (as suggested in the comment above):

$$q(x) = (x-\eta)^T A(x-\eta) + \eta^T A \eta$$

take $x = \alpha u + \eta$ so that the first term above goes to $-\infty$ as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$. The second term is constant. This shows that $q$ does not have a solution.